# What is this thing that goes zipping past the Electron launch?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, physics, identify-this-object

Watching the Electron launch 07 October 2022 on https://www.rocketlabusa.com/live-stream, what do I see in the video at T + 9:12, just after they confirm secondary engine cut off?

[image]

I thought it was a satellite that went zipping by, but it makes an arc, and comes back on the bottom right of the screen. It seems like the Electron rocket catches up with it. Is it something falling off the rocket? Or a passing satellite? Or, if we can't identify it, why does it appear to come back on the bottom right of the screen? I would never have guessed those physics could be possible.

What's going on here?

In case the livestream link goes away, here's the Youtube link, cued 5 seconds before it appears:

Comment: It happens at about -47:06 in the confusingly-timestamped recording of the stream, from a cursory glance it looks like a speck of something that fell off the rocket while it's coasting, just before the stage containing the camera and the engine it's watching was jettisoned.

Comment: Hm, scratch that timestamp, the ongoing stream gave confusing timestamps. Now that it's ended, it happens at about 36:10.

Comment: Looks to be out of focus, so likely very close to the camera.